# Can’t print tables from a database with JDBC

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

I'm trying to figure out how to get this piece of code, initially made for MySQL, to work with (Microsoft) SQL Server.
When it's called, it's supposed to print out the flight destinations stored as tables in the database, (`dbo.`) `London`, (`dbo.`) `NewYork` etc. But right now, it won't print anything, no errors either.. I’m using the default MSSQL schema name, `dbo`.

```
public void viewFlights(Connection conn) throws SQLException {
    String SCHEMA_NAME="${dbo}";

    try {
        DatabaseMetaData metaData = conn.getMetaData();
        String[] tableType = {"TABLE"};

        ResultSet rs = metaData.getTables(null, SCHEMA_NAME, null, tableType);
            while (rs.next()) {
                String tableName = rs.getString(3);
                System.out.println(tableName);
            }

        } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Any idea what I've missed here?

Comment: The schema name you are using is `${dbo}`, have you tried just `dbo`?

Comment: Agree with "check the schema name".  It appears that you mean some variable 'dbo' to be interpolated into it, but `getTables()` will not do anything of the sort. Additionally: storing data in table names is an ... interesting .... design decision (and fraught with peril).  Please reconsider - for example some rdbms (I think MySQL is one) will not preserve capitalization / encoding as you might expect for db object names.   Also also: you almost certainly want to start using try-with-resources for `ResultSet`.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft That did the trick, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by [David Browne's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7297700/david-browne-microsoft) comment!

Answer (score 0):

Either set a default scheme for you database or
Use Schema name as
String SCHEMA_NAME="{schema.dbo}";

Comment: Simply replacing ```"${dbo}"```with ```"dbo"``` as suggested by @DavidBrowne-Microsoft solved it. 
I'm not sure if I misunderstood your answer, but ```String SCHEMA_NAME="{schema.dbo}";``` didn't return anything. I could just change the schema, but the DB is created by another piece of code so I figured the default would do to not clutter it up too much.